# Oulook script - How to find the root folder of a favorite folder

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, favorite

I am trying to find a way to access the associated public folder of a favorite folder. The goal is to move mails automatically to public folders. In the case where this folder has been defined as favorite, I would like to move the mail to this favorite folder for performance issues.

The related public folder path is simply visible on outlook in the favorite folder properties (right click on folder then properties/summary : the path of the public folder is shown there) but i can't find a way to access the information programmatically...

I would really appreciate your help!

Many Thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

I have used EWS to access the PR_FAV_PUBLIC_SOURCE_KEY by using the ExtendedPropertyDefinition

```
new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C02, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
```

converting it to an entry id should bring you to the correct public folder.
Details: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/exchangesvrdevelopmentlegacy/thread/e75940c6-b53b-4260-b12c-6541e4ff8a69

And there are more favorite specific properties, like:

```
    private ExtendedPropertyDefinition eProp_LevelMask = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7D03, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
    private ExtendedPropertyDefinition eProp_ShortcutType = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7D09, MapiPropertyType.String);
    private ExtendedPropertyDefinition eProp_FavParent = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7D02, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
```

and

```
    private ExtendedPropertyDefinition eProp_ShortcutName = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C00, MapiPropertyType.String);
    private ExtendedPropertyDefinition eProp_ShortcutAlias = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C01, MapiPropertyType.String);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I am a beginner and I am scripting in VBA. This code is C right?
Do you know how to script that in visual basic ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, dont know much about EWS and VBA. But you can still access extended properties via PropertyAccessor I guess... More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff869865.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Sub example1()
Dim strFinal As String
Dim strline As String

Open "D:\textfile.txt" For Input As #1
    While EOF(1) = False
        Line Input #1, strline
        If Len(strline) > 24 Then
            strFinal = strFinal + ModifyColumn(strline)
            Else
            strFinal = strFinal + strline + vbCrLf
        End If
    Wend
    strFinal = strFinal
Close #1

Open "D:\textfile.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, strFinal
Close #1
End Sub

Function ModifyColumn(ByVal strInput As String) As String
    Dim arrString() As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    'split the columns
    arrString = Split(strInput, vbTab)
    'concatenate the first 2 column as they are
    strOutput = arrString(0) + vbTab + arrString(1) + vbTab + arrString(2)
    'add 100$ to column3
    requirevalue = Left(arrString(3), InStr(1, arrString(3), "|") - 1)
    last3Digit = Right(requirevalue, 3)
    If Left(requirevalue, 3) = "max" Then
        Newvalue = vbTab + "OTPxxxxxx" & last3Digit & "|" & Right(arrString(3), Len(arrString(3)) - InStr(1, arrString(3), "|")) + vbCrLf
    Else
        Newvalue = vbTab + arrString(3) + vbCrLf
    End If
    strOutput = strOutput & Newvalue
    'strOutput = strOutput + Strings.Trim(Str(CDbl(Left(arrString(3), Len(arrString(2)) - 1)) + 100)) + "$" + vbCrLf
    ModifyColumn = strOutput
End Function